# AUTO IT & Selenium Not able to send keys to JAVA Applet (Oracle Flexcube Application)

Tags: java, xml, selenium, xpath, autoit

I am using mixture of autoit + selenium where i am trying to automate Oracle Flexcube application which is like java Applet.

I have used JVM-Inspector for identifying the swing/AWT elements of the UI.

```
WebElement textF = aDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@instance = '214']"));
textF.clear();
textF.click();
aDriver.getKeyboard().sendKeys(new String[] { "01/02/2018"});
```

Here cursor is moving to the VTextField (as shown in the jvm-inspector) , but `clear()` is not working and also `sendKeys()` is also not working.

I have tried everything but keyboard gets lock. If i put `Thread.sleep(5000);` and try to enter keys from the keyboard while execution is going on , keyboard gets lock. Here `aDriver` is `autoitdriver`.

Comment: Try `textF.sendKeys()` instead of `aDriver.getKeyboard().sendKeys()` to send directly to the control in question. Does textF.click() actually focus the control? If so, try inserting `sleep(1000)` between each statement - this may be a timing issue - keys are sent before the browser finished changing focus. Is there a good reason AutoIT driver is used instead of traditional ones?

Comment: i am using AutoIT driver as it is not web application it is Oracle's flexcube application. I have to launch particular URL , after hitting that java application opens up so may be it is java applet or java swing/awt app i dont know exactly. I did what you said but still it is not working.  I used "SIKULI" took image  of the field and used screen.DoubleClick() and screen.type() method to type , IT WORKED. but i dont want to use sikuli , Please tell me reason why keyboard gets lock while using autoit driver

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood then, sorry. Please clarify what exactly does `keyboard gets lock` mean? Try to determine which statement (`find()`, `clear()`, `click()` or `sendKeys()`) triggers the problem by removing some of them from your script.

Comment: Try running a standalone AutoIt script the same way you used sikuli to see if the problem is related to autoit itself. I have successfully used a standalone AutoIT script to interact with JAVA form, although selecting an individual control did not work and TAB-ing was glitched on this form, so I had to resort to simulating mouse clicks. Once I ran into a related(?) problem when AutoIT somehow caused the form to stop reacting to any input (keyboard, mouse,etc). I was only able to solve that by adding huge delays between any interactions that caused this behavior and even then it was not perfect

Comment: Sure i ll try running individual autoit Script ! "keyboard gets lock" meaning for e.g there is VtextField which has some default Date by xpath or any other way i can locate the textfield cursor goes there and also highlights that date , but after reaching there if write command "sendkeys" it does not work that field does not take any input from sendkeys , and even i interrupt and try to sendkeys manually using keyboard that textfield does not take any input , it does not even clear , so resulting in "keyboard lock scenario"

Comment: Only that individual text-input control gets locked or whole window, or whole process? Does it respond to mouse clicks? Does it play a "ding" sound when you click outside the control? Does it appear hung (i.e. window becomes "pales" and prompts to terminate?  Do you run another program that may intercept or emulate keyboard or mouse input such as on-the-fly keyboard layout switcher (punto, mahou, etc), virtual machine, remote administration tool (VNC), fullscreen application, kiosk/video-surveillance software, something that uses a very unconventional global hotkey (such as numlock)?

Comment: No i did not hear any ding sound and also screen has radio buttons , so they do takes mouse clicks , i can click on radio buttons and can change the fields  , only the text fields are not taking any input. and i am working in a company where we connect to CLIENTS VDI and then we work on that VDI , So there local system and  then theres VDI and i am running this code on VDI not on local  machine

Comment: Wierd. Please test which statement ( `clear()`, `click()`, or `SendKeys()` ) actually triggers the problem? Does a standalone autoit script (i.e. when you run *.au3 file) cause similar issue? Does `textF.sendKeys()` do anything? What would happen if you temporarily comment out all of your script code except key sending - does it still fail same way? Does adding large sleep between click() and sendKeys() change anything? Does trying to input just one letter `sendKeys("x")` change anything? Do you have hieroglyphic support enabled on the computer, such as Chinese?

Comment: I tried it using Sikuli api , captured image of the textbox and used screen.type() to type on textfield and it worked fine.

Comment: Please at least test *all* of my suggestions and post the results. You may have ran into some complicated issue so if you want any useful help you should provide exhaustive information on the subject.